# Acumatica - PXSelector Value Cannot be Found in the System

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Acumatica Version 21.203.0026

I have a filter DAC on an inquiry screen that has a PXSelector for a Pay Group and a PXSelector for a Pay Period. The Pay Period PXSelector is disabled until the Pay Group PXSelector has a value so that the user can only select Pay Periods that belong to that Pay Group. The PXSelectors have the AutoRefresh attribute set to true.

For some reason, whenever I select a Pay Period, the Pay Period ID shows in the PXSelector along with the DescriptionField, and immediately after the value shows, the DescriptionField disappears and a PXSetPropertyException is thrown on the Pay Period ID PXSelector with the message "'Pay Period' cannot be found in the system".

I'm not really sure why it cannot be found in the system if it is showing up in the PXSelector and showing in the control for a moment.

Here is the trace error:

```
Error: 'Pay Period' cannot be found in the system.

   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.throwNoItem(String[] restricted, Boolean external, Object value)
   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.Verify(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e, Object& item)
   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldVerifying(String name, Object row, Object& newValue, Boolean externalCall)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.FillWithValues(TNode item, TNode copy, IDictionary values, PXCacheOperation operation, Boolean externalCall)
```

Here is the trace information:

```
The item PayPeriodID is not found (restricted:False,external:True,value:112020)
```

Here is my filter DAC:

```
    [PXHidden]
    public class EarningDetailFilter : IBqlTable
    {
        #region EmployeeID
        [PXInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Employee")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(SearchFor<EPEmployee.bAccountID>), 
            SubstituteKey = typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD), 
            DescriptionField = typeof(EPEmployee.acctName))]
        public virtual int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public abstract class employeeID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<employeeID> { }
        #endregion

        #region PayGroupID
        [PXString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Pay Group")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(SearchFor<PRPayGroup.payGroupID>.
            Where<MatchWithPayGroup<PRPayGroup.payGroupID>>), 
        DescriptionField = typeof(PRPayGroup.description))]
        public virtual string PayGroupID { get; set; }
        public abstract class payGroupID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<payGroupID> { }
        #endregion

        #region PayPeriodID
        [PXString(6, InputMask = "CC-####")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Pay Period")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(SearchFor<PRPayGroupPeriod.finPeriodID>.
            Where<PRPayGroupPeriod.payGroupID.
                IsEqual<EarningDetailFilter.payGroupID.FromCurrent>>),
            DescriptionField = typeof(PRPayGroupPeriod.descr))]
        public virtual string PayPeriodID { get; set; }
        public abstract class payPeriodID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<payPeriodID> { }
        #endregion
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

In the database, FinPeriodID is stored as the concatenation of the Year and the PeriodNbr, in that order. For some reason, the value that is brought into the PXSelector when a record is selected is the concatenation of the PeriodNbr and the Year, in that order.

So, when the `Verify` method of the PXSelector is executed, it is looking for the FinPeriodID with the PeriodNbr first. After it looks for the record in the database and doesn't find it, it switches the internal value of the FinPeriodID back to the correct value with the Year first. I'm not positive, but this seems like a logical error on Acumatica's part.

I fixed this by using the `PRPayGroupPeriodIDAttribute` and using dummy fields for the StartDate, EndDate, and TransactionDate, which are required parameters for the attribute.

Comment: My first thought would be that you may not have Commit Changes set on the PayGroupID field so the server side verification is failing and causing the field to be cleared.

Comment: CommitChanges is set

Answer (score 0):

`PayPeriodID` references `EarningDetailFilter.payGroupID` in the query:

```
SearchFor<PRPayGroupPeriod.finPeriodID>.
    Where<PRPayGroupPeriod.payGroupID.
        IsEqual<EarningDetailFilter.payGroupID.FromCurrent>>
```

`PayGroupID` uses `MatchWithPayGroup` BQL operator:

```
SearchFor<PRPayGroup.payGroupID>.
    Where<MatchWithPayGroup<PRPayGroup.payGroupID>>
```

Method `MatchWithPayGroup<Field>.Verify` could be throwing an exception.

Try simplifying the expression and make sure expected data exists in database table:

```
SearchFor<PRPayGroupPeriod.finPeriodID>
```